# DEFLATE compression example and bytes organization

Tags: python, compression, zip, deflate

I'm starting at LZ77 compression and I've read all the google links about deflate, huffman, and LZ77 compression. I understood exactly how these compression works, and I know exactly how to implement it in a text way, BUT:

I don't know do I make it the right way so it can be decoded by any zip decoder. I mean, I don't know what to do with the bytes and so, since when I want to indicate a pointer, I don't know which bytes indicate this pointer and so... And I don't know about the trees representation. Could someone give me a simple example of a compression in BYTES level? I wanna know how to implement it with a .zip file. I swear it is now about being lazy, it's because I can't find good explanations of everything. 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is not intelligible.  It does not sound like you understand what you claim to understand.  You may just need to do more reading on compression.

Comment: @MarkAdler I don't speak native english, so I'm doing the most I can to understand. I really understood how the compression works, but not in bytes lever, only in 'text level'. I want to know about the headers of a zip file, and the blocks and so :(

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "text level" or "bytes level".  You may be missing the point that compressed data is written as a stream of _bits_.

Comment: But data is written at bytes, isn't it? I can only write bytes to the memory?

Comment: You are mixing together Zip and Zlib, zlib is compression algorithm and described in RFC 1950 and 1951, while ZIP - is archive format which uses ZLib as underlying compression algorithm, and it is decribed in Zip APPNOTE by PKWare. And yes, data to memory is written in bytes, but zlib works with bits.

Comment: Each byte consists of eight bits.

Comment: Please refer to the comments in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140280/lz77-compression-reserved-bytes) for references to the deflate and zip formats.